# Ajax query result success call multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call where success function is called twice. I tried to analyze but not getting why it is getting called twice.

I am using a for loop to call ajax functionality and inside that I am calling second ajax inside success function based on a condition `(f==i+1)`. If the condition matches then it will call second ajax functionality, but what is happening is that, after the loop is over, inside the success of first ajax call is calling     `alert("Check call");` twice. It should call only once if `i=1` in the loop.
What is happening in first loop is the condition doesn't go to success and when the loop is over then it goes to success of first ajax as many time as loop happen and `f` become 2 and `i+1` become 2 so it will check condition two times.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
    $(document).on("click", "#Rsub1", function (e) {
        if ($("#Rvno").val() == "" || $("#Rvno").val() == null) {
            alert("Please enter Vendor no");
        } else {
            for (var f = 0; f <= i; f++) {
                (function (index) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../Home/RaisePReq",
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (r) {
                            if (f == i + 1) {
                                alert("Check call");
                                var fieldvals
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "../Home/gridtbl",
                                    data: JSON.stringify(fieldvals),
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    success: function (r) {
                                        $('#grdtbl').html(r);
                                        //jQuery.noConflict();
                                        $('#ipcelltbl').DataTable({
                                            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                                            buttons: [
                                                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                                            ]
                                        });
                                    },
                                    failure: function () {
                                        alert("Error");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function () {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                })(f);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi what is `i` here ? Also why you are checking `if (f == i + 1) {` inside success function ? Please elaborate .

Comment: @Swati is a global variable i have declared it is taking value from there.

Comment: Is it necessary to put `if (f == i + 1) {` condition inside success ? Why not put that outside ajax call ? If the condition is `true` then your `first -ajax` and `second ajax` will get executed and if not true it will not enter inside ajax .

Answer (score 1):

Hi @sam Welcome to SO,

Take a flag, initialize as **false** in start before success script, if got success then put flag **true** in the bottom end of success script , and also put a statement in the start of success script to check if flag **true** then exit etc.

[image]

Comment: @waquar can you please show the syntax i am not aware of flag and how to use in my case.

Comment: @Sam Please, have a view of my edited answer. I am not hands on coding nowadays please try to show you a complete sequence of coding , there defining flag(boolean) variable as you asked too.

Answer (score 0):

```
if i = 1
then
for (var f = 0; f <= i; f++) {
for (var f = 0; 0 <= 1; f++)
for (var f = 1; 1 <= 1; f++)
stop because    2 <= 1 is false.
if i = 1 then for loop running 2 times.
```

Comment: i put condition in success if(f=i+1) if this condition match then condition inside it should run but it is running twice.

Comment: you can try with if (f==i) instead of try i +1.

Comment: i tried waht happen in first loop it goes out of loop withouth going in success and checking condition .and after second lop over it goes to success and check if(f==i) but at that time variables  f=2 & i=1  and it didn't check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

For loop first initialize the variable then checks for condition and then execute some code and increment or decrement variable. In your case when i=1, then on first execution it checks if f<=i and f is zero, it will execute first time. After that it increments f to 1
and checks if f<=1 which is true, it will execute one more time. To prevent this you can add if (f<i) which stops after single execution only.

Comment: i am checking condition at suceess looping is ok but in succes it didn't goes in first loop when second loop over then it goes there and checking condition as much time as much loop happened.

Comment: @Sam, According to this (f == i + 1) , alert("Check call") this shouldn't get executed even once. Because when loop runs f will always be less than or equal to i but never will be equal to (i+1). Can you console.log i variable when it is exceuting twice.